# Attaching a concrete coffee table top to reclaimed oak sleeper legs with a high moisture content

Tags: concrete, wood, table

hopefully the heading is succint enough. I am about to cast a 44" by 21" gfc concrete coffee table top that will be 1 1/2" thick. I want to rest it onto some green (40% moisture) sleeper legs that are resting on their length at either end.

Whilst i appreciate the weight will reduce the table top moving i want to make sure that it cant slip too far.

I dont want to glue due to wood movement and the horrendous weight so was wondering if placing dowels within the concrete and and using a forstner bit of a larger diameter in the wood would suffice and allow for any potential wood movement. I was also thinking of pushing the legs a few mm into the concrete for the first half hour of the cure to create an impression.

The table will be used inside and i am located in the UK where we have a reasonably high atmospheric moisture content although the central heating will be kicking in soon.

Any alternatives would be very much appreciated, many thanks!

Comment: Can you provide any more detail, maybe a sketch, on what the leg system will look like?  FWIW, your top will weigh in the neighborhood of 120 pounds.  I'd be mostly concerned that it can't fall on anyone!

Comment: Are you adding rebar to the concrete slab for break resistance?     Then bend those pieces on each end and let the rebar stick out

Answer (score 1):

Why not bolt on some brackets? At 1 1/2" thick dfrc you can drill the piece and screw some brackets on with concrete screws. 
Your probably better off putting the wood in the house for a week or two to lose some of the moisture before assembly.